# How to select first table data based on another table based on one column successor value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have two tables, I need to select the data from both table based on one condition. My tables structure is

```
create table Las(name nvarchar(50), Depth int);
insert into Las values('testName1', 25);
insert into Las values('testName2', 76);
insert into Las values('testName3', 31);
insert into Las values('testName4', 24);

create table Calci(name nvarchar(50), Depth int, carbon int, calcium int);
insert into Calci values('testName1', 24,30,10);
insert into Calci values('testName1', 30,25,15);
insert into Calci values('testName1', 31,24,16);
insert into Calci values('testName2', 75,25,15);
insert into Calci values('testName2', 80,24,16);
insert into Calci values('testName2', 85,28,25);
```

***Condition: Select table 1 Name, Depth along with table 2 carbon and calium column based on the table 1 depth very next depth in table 2.*** So my final output will be like this.

[image: Output]

Comment: can you create sql fiddle for the above tale structure and also share what you tried

Comment: What is your question here exactly? You seemed to have forgotten to ask one.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande I have tried like what George Menoutis answerd below. but some modification required, His answer is perfect

Comment: @Larnu I tried to select the combained data from this two tables with above hilighted condetion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, changing the names of your_first_table and your_second_table:

```
select t1.name,t1.Depth,q.carbon,q.calcium
from your_first_table t1
outer apply
(
    select top 1 carbon,calcium
    from your_second_table t2
    where 
        t2.name=t1.name
        and t2.Depth>t1.Depth -- From all the highest,....
    order by t2.Depth asc -- get the smaller
)q
```

Comment: @Jzl,can you explain why yout output has only 2 rows.It should be atleast 4 rows.I think above query will also return 4 rows.

Comment: @KumarHarsh Above query If there is no matching data in second table it will return null. In my case its ok,

Comment: If instead of null you want to have no rows at all, you can replace outer apply with cross apply

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis Its working fine for small data. In my table I have 30k+ data in both table, Now the exicution time taking more than 5 minutes. Is there any alternate solution for this.?

Comment: Questions of "how to make it run faster" are typically much more difficult. First, copy-paste in your question the PK and all the indexes of your table. Hopefully there is an index on (name,depth), if not you could make them. In the end, the only way for us to search this is to paste here the execution plan,

Answer (score 0):

I would use `APPLY` :

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.Depth, t2.carbon, t2.calium 
FROM table1 t1 CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) t2.*
      FROM table2 t2
      WHERE t2.name = t1.name AND t2.Depth > t1.Depth
      ORDER BY t2.Depth 
     ) t2;
```